# DXA 2.0 CTP website internal server error Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-2.0

`enter code here`We are configuring DXA 2.0 CTP .Net website on windows server 2008 R2 .All microservice are configured on same server.While accessing the website getting below error in site.log file

```
ERROR - Failed to execute query
Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ServiceQueryException: Failed to execute query ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException: {"timestamp":"2017-12-06T14:36:19.241+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientHttpError","message":"Unable to get response from OData service: No Response.","path":"/ModelService/GetPublicationMappingsFunctionImport(Url='http://gbk-staging.khayal.net/')"}
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.InnerSynchExecute[TElement](Uri requestUri, String httpMethod, Nullable`1 singleResult, OperationParameter[] operationParameters)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.Execute[TElement](Uri requestUri)
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass19_1`1.<Execute>b__1()
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Caching.CacheHandlers.DefaultMemCache.DefaultMemCacheHandler`1.SetOrGetExisting(String key, String region, Func`1 valueFactory, CacheItemPolicy cacheItemPolicy)
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.AbstractODataService.HandleHttpResponseCode(Exception e, Int32 statusCode)
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.PerformRetry[T](Func`1 block, Int32 retryCount)
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.Retry[T](Func`1 block, Int32 retryCount, Boolean locking)
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.DynamicMappingsRetrieverImpl.GetPublicationMapping(String url)
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.DynamicMappingsRetriever.GetPublicationMapping(String url)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.CdApiLocalizationResolver.ResolveLocalization(Uri url) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\CdApiLocalizationResolver.cs:line 66
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.get_Localization() in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Configuration\WebRequestContext.cs:line 25
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.StaticContentModule.BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXAuto\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Statics\StaticContentModule.cs:line 54
```

Below error in cd_client.log file

```
    ERROR [Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.ContentServiceProvider..ctor]
            The service endpoint 'http://10.0.0.47:8085/ModelService/$metadata' was not reachable so version information is no longer available.

Error in dxa file for model-service is

 Error handling return value [type=org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity] [value=<500 Internal Server Error,{timestamp=Thu Dec 07 12:54:41 AST 2017, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, exception=com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientRuntimeException, message=Unable to perform action, path=/ModelService/RequestStartActionImport},{}>]
    HandlerMethod details: 
    Controller [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController]
    Method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]

    org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:130)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:394)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:395)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:254)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:349)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(Nio2Endpoint.java:1609)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.processSocket(AbstractEndpoint.java:830)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$Nio2SocketWrapper$4.completed(Nio2Endpoint.java:639)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$Nio2SocketWrapper$4.completed(Nio2Endpoint.java:617)
        at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: And if you try opening that url in a browser? Do you get any response?

Comment: @NunoLinhares when i try to access 'http://10.0.0.47:8085/ModelService/$metadata' i m getting this  error
"There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Unable to get response from OData service: No Response."

Comment: @NunoLinhares please see the edit i have added error logged in dxa file for model-service

Comment: Looks like you content service is not responding, or throwing an error. Can you try connecting to it via a browser too?

Comment: yes i tried and it is throwing same error which i updated in my question

Comment: This is the model service, not the content service: http://10.0.0.47:8085/ModelService/$metadata

Comment: @NunoLinhares there was typo in ContentServiceCapability url inside discovery service config file after fixing that i m getting a new error "ERROR - No View Model registered for View 'Core:Region:header'. Check that you have registered this View in the 'Core' area registration." inside site.log.I have also published Publish Setting Page and other pages .

Comment: Probably worth answering this one with your fix, and ask a new question about the new error.

Answer (score 1):

There was typo for ContentServiceCapability url inside discovery service config file after fixing the url and registering again using "java -jar discovery-registration.jar update" command fix this problem